# Scala Quasiquotes Destructuring a Type

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

**Context:**

I'm working on a library for working with JMX in Scala. One of the objectives is to have a strong typed interface to Managed Beans. I guess akin to to the Spring framework JMX library.

**Objective:** Macro to Deserialise TabularData to a case class:

```
// interface for which I'd like to generate an implementation using a macro
trait JMXTabularAssembler[T <: Product] {
  def assemble(data: TabularData): T
}

object JMXAnnotations {
  case class Attribute(name: String) extends StaticAnnotation
}
case class example(
  @Attribute("name") name: String,
  @Attribute("age") age: Int,
  unmarked: String
)
```

**Problem:** There are plenty of examples of composing tree's using the `q""` interpolators. But I can't figure out how to use the `tq""` interpolator to 
extract the fields out of a case class from a type context.

```
private def mkAssembler[T <: Product : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.universe.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val tt = weakTypeOf[T]
}
```

**Question:** How do I use the QuasiQuote machinery to destructure the fields of my case class so that *I can loop over them* and filter out fields with my annotation (**my `Attribute` annotation is not available from the approach I am currently taking"**). An implementation of the following that returns the fields with annotations in declaration order is what I am after.

```
private def harvestFieldsWithAnnotations[T<: Product: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): 
    List[(c.universe.Name, String, c.universe.Type,   List[c.universe.Annotation])] = ???
```

**Bonus:** The objective is to get the attribute fields, generate trees for each field that extract the field from the `TabularData` and use these trees to create the `JMXTabularAssembler` Functor. If you could show me how to do this for the example above it would bootstrap my efforts :D.

---

**What I have tried:** I started solving the problem by using reflection. This does not seem the right way to do it. Snippets:

```
...
val dec = tt.decls.sorted
def getFields = dec.withFilter( t=> t.isTerm && ! t.isMethod)
def getCaseAccessors = dec.withFilter( t => t.isMethod && t.asMethod.isCaseAccessor)

dec.foreach { d=>
  println(d.name, d.annotations)
}

getFields.foreach { f =>
  println(f.annotations)
}

val types = getCaseAccessors.map { d =>
  println(d.annotations)
  (d.name, tt.member(d.name).asMethod.returnType)
}
...
```

Comment: This link has a lot of useful information: [link](http://www.strongtyped.io/blog/2014/05/23/case-class-related-macros/). It looks similar to the approach described, and I doubt it will return the annotations. It also does not quasi quotes but the raw api.

Answer (score 0):

The following method does the trick, it does not use quasi quotes. The key is to access the backing field of a symbol representing the field accessor of a case class (the `accessed` call).

```
private def harvestFieldsWithAnnotations[T <: Product : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context) = {
    import c.universe._
    val tt = weakTypeOf[T]

    tt.decls.sorted.filter(t => t.isMethod && t.asMethod.isCaseAccessor).map { ca =>
      val asMethod = tt.member(ca.name).asMethod
      (ca.name, asMethod.returnType, asMethod.accessed.annotations)
    }
  }
```

Field annotations won't get retained unless they are explicitly annotated with `scala.annotation.meta.field`.

So the `Attribute` annotation should be:

```
@field
case class Attribute(name: String) extends StaticAnnotation
```